# Compiling VSTS Extension in VisualStudio 2017

Tags: azure-devops, tsc, azure-artifacts

How to build a VSTS extension in Visual Studio 2017. The post build event configured in package.json doesn't work from Visual Studio.

Only the Command npm run build triggers the build and postbuild events. I want vsix file to be created on building the VisualStudio 2017 project.

[image: This is my package.json file]

Comment: Please show code as embedded code in the question, not as a picture.

Comment: It should work, did you get any error message? What's your project type?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot build directly to generate the vsix file in VS. Just as you said we can only trigger the postbuild events to call the command `tfx extension create --manifest-globs vss-extension.json` to package it.

To create TFS/VSTS extensions, you can refer to this article for detials :[Create your first extension with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/get-started/visual-studio?view=vsts)

To package as the vsix file, please see [Packaging and publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/overview?view=vsts) - [Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/publish/overview?view=vsts#package)

If you mean create Visual Studio VSIX Package, then you can reference below articles:

- [Creating Your First Visual Studio VSIX Package](https://dzone.com/articles/creating-your-first-visual-studio-vsix-package)
- [Visual Studio Extensibility: Creating Visual Studio VSIX package
  extension](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37071.visual-studio-extensibility-creating-visual-studio-vsix-package-extension.aspx)